# как map ищет значение по ключу

Tags: java

map перебирает все элементы по ключу до соответствия или как это происходит?

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(0, 0); map.put(1, 1);
    System.out.println(map.get(0));
```

Comment: Map - это интерфейс, в данном случае используется HashMap реализация, а это [хэш-таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0). Также есть и другие реализации, например TreeMap, использующее такую структуру как [Красно-чёрное дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) и у них разные алгоритмы получение доступа к элементу. У хэш-таблицы это хэш функция, с помощью которой получают индекс на нужный элемент (на деле всё немного сложнее).

Answer (score 0):

Реализация Map.get

```
final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
        Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
        if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
            (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
            if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
                ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                return first;
            if ((e = first.next) != null) {
                if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                    return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
                do {
                    if (e.hash == hash &&
                        ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                        return e;
                } while ((e = e.next) != null);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```